# Convert an NSArray of byte values into an NSData

Tags: nsarray, nsdata

I have an array returned from a web service containing byte values (non binary format, i.e. 0-255). These represent a thumbnail image. I want need to create an NSData object from these values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[+ (id)dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithBytes%3alength%3a) is your friend:

```
void bytesToNSDataExample() {
    unsigned char bytes[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:5];

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);

    // if data was a image like in your case, you would probably do something like this:
    NSImageRep *imgRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:data];
}
```